# Задача по созданию из bean класса proxy и фабрики по созданию объектов - Java EE

Tags: java, proxy, аннотации

Есть задача.

Создайте способность объектов действовать как прокси вместо использования исходного поведения. Таким образом, для расширения таких функциональных возможностей реализация должна включать аннотацию для маркировки доступности класса для прокси-сервера и фабрики для получения объектов. Необходимые детали:
Создайте аннотацию @Proxy. Аннотация может появляться на классах и объявляет, что класс владельца может стать прокси. Атрибуты:
InvocationHandler - имя класса для использования в качестве обработчика
Создайте фабричный класс. Класс используется для получения экземпляра объекта для класса, предоставленного как атрибут. Методы:
GetInstanceOf (класс) - метод для получения объекта для указанного класса. Если класс имеет аннотацию @Proxy, то вместо обычного экземпляра следует использовать прокси-объект.

помогите разобраться в порядке выполнения, что за чем следует и как это должно правильно работать. Опыта мало, в голове очень плохо все складывается. Всем заранее спасибо.
Буду рад любым примерам и наставлениям.

Для лучшего понимания смысла задания вот оригнал текста задачи:

0
голос «против»
accept
Оригинал текста задания.

Create an ability for objects to act as a proxy instead of using the original behaviour. Thus to extend such functionality an implementation should include an annotation to mark class availability to be proxy and a factory to obtain objects. 
Required details: 
Create a @Proxy annotation. The annotation may appear on classes and declares that a holder class can become proxy. 
Attributes: invocationHandler - a class name for using as handler Create a factory class. 
The class is used to get an object instance for a class provided as attribute.

Methods: getInstanceOf(Class) - a method to get an object for the specified class. 
If the class has the @Proxy annotation applied then a proxy object should be used instead of the common instance

Основные направления: создать фабрику, которая проверяет, есть ли на целевом классе аннотация @proxy, если есть, возвращает прокси-объект, иначе возвращает сам объект.

Answer (score 2):

интерфейс

```
package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities;

public interface Animals {
    void  voice();
}
```

класс прокси КОТ

```
package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities;

import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.annotations.Proxy;

@Proxy(invocationHandler = "tasks.reflections.annotation.handlers.ProxyAnnotationHandler")
public class Cat implements Animals {

    @Override
    public void voice() {
        System.out.println("Mrrr-mau");

    }


}
```

класс простых собак:

```
package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities;

public class Dog implements Animals {

    @Override
    public void voice() {
        System.out.println("Grrr-gav");

    }


}
```

прокси класс выглядит так:

```
package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.annotations;


import java.lang.annotation.*;

/**
 *
 */
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Proxy {
    String invocationHandler();
}
```

Далее фабрика:

```
package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.factories;

import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities.Animals;

public interface AnimalsCreator {

    Animals factoryMethod();

}


package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.factories;


import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities.Animals;
import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities.Cat;



public class CatCreator  implements AnimalsCreator {

    @Override
    public Animals factoryMethod() {

        return new Cat();
    }




    }


package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.factories;

import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities.Animals;
import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities.Dog;

public class DogCreator implements AnimalsCreator {

    @Override
    public Animals factoryMethod() {

        return new Dog();
    }

}
```

Ну и раннер

```
package by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.runner;

import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.entities.Animals;
import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.factories.AnimalsCreator;
import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.factories.CatCreator;
import by.tranning.ReflectionHomePartA.factories.DogCreator;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnimalsCreator createAnimal = makeAnimalByName("dog");

        Animals animal = createAnimal.factoryMethod();
        animal.voice();

    }

    public static AnimalsCreator makeAnimalByName(String kindAnimal) {

        if (kindAnimal.equals("dog")) {
            return new DogCreator();
        }
        if (kindAnimal.equals("cat")) {
            return new CatCreator();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("This kind of anmal deas not exsist" + kindAnimal);
    }
}
```

подскажите как теперь организовать фабрику, что бы она проверила по аннотации создается прокси объект или простой.

и как добавить сюда прокси?